# Can't filter data with Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, filter, angular-reactive-forms

I am mostly new at Angular . I have a  page with a list of posts. I want to filter the lists of posts with the search box, but the input field does not filter the data .I can not use ngModel because I am using Reactive Forms. I think it has something to do with the input in the view.  I really do not know what to do anymore . This is my code.

```
<div class="b-posts">
<form class="b-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(this.postForm.value)" [formGroup]="postForm">
<div class=" b-form__group form-group">
  <span class="b-form__circle"></span>
  <input type="text" name="post" placeholder="Type" class="b-form__input form-control"
    formControlName="text">
</div>
   <div class="b-form__filter form-group">
     <input type="text" formControlName="search">
    </div>
 </form>
  <div *ngFor="let post of filteredPosts">
      {{post.text}}
 </div>
<div class="b-post" *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <div class="b-post__main">
    <div class="b-post__info">
    <span class="b-post__circle"></span>
    <div>
     <p class="b-post__p">{{post.name}}</p>
      <p class="b-post__time">{{post.time}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-post__dots"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="b-post__text">{{post.text}}</p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  The component.ts

   @Component({
    selector: 'app-posts-list',
     templateUrl: './posts-list.component.html',
     styleUrls: [ './posts-list.component.scss' ]
     })
    export class PostsListComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Post[];
    filteredPosts: Post[];
    private _search: string;

    get search(): string {
    return this._search;
    }

    set search(value: string) {
    this._search = value;
    this.filteredPosts = this.filter(value);
    
    }

   postForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [],
    name: [ 'ImePrezime' ],
    time: [],
    text: [ '' ],
    search: []
});

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postListService.getPosts().subscribe((post) => {
        this.posts = post;
    });
    this.filteredPosts = this.posts;
}

filter(data: string) {
    return this.posts.filter((post) => post.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use change events to trigger the data filter on search input as shown below:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="search" (change)="filterData()">


filterData () {
    this.filter(this.postForm.get('search').value);
}

filter(data: string) {
  if (!data) return;
  return this.posts.filter((post) => post.text && post.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}
```

You can also use (keyup) event if you want to trigger filter for every key press

Comment: I have made the exact same thing as you wrote, but there is an error showing . When I type in the search box  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined is showing .

Comment: Then the problem is with your filter() function related to the `posts` data. Check what's coming by consoling it

Comment: You need to check both the `posts.text` and the `data` as well. They both are to be expected as string for `.toLowerCase()` to work

Comment: I have made changes and the same error appears

Comment: filter(data: string) {
  this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter((p: Post) => {
   return p.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  });
 }

Comment: Console data.toLowerCase() and you will see that data is coming fine. I.e., `console.log(data.toLowerCase())` or you can also alert() it

Comment: Also tell me what's the output for `console.log(posts)`

Comment: When I console.log(data.toLowerCase()) the input value is shown (as I am typing) . And when I console.log(posts)  the object of posts is shown.

Comment: Tell me whats `console.log(JSON.stringify(posts));` as far as I can see, the problem is in your `posts` not in search input since you said that `data` is coming correctly as you are typing which was the original question that you asked here.

Comment: I'm expecting posts to be `[{..., text: 'some string', ...}, ..., {..., text: 'data', ...}]`

Comment: According to your code the `posts` variable is an array of objects with a key `text` having string data coming from some api I suppose.

Comment: The array of posts is shown when I type console.log(JSON.stringify(posts)) . Just like this  ([{"id":2,"name":"Ime Prezime ","time":"","text":""}... )

Comment: Okay good so you see here your post.text is empty which means its null when converted from json to object and when we try to call toLowerCase() on it then it will throw error. So what you need to do now is to first check if its not empty only after then you will do your filter.

Comment: @Sarah Barlow check my answer now. I updated it for null cases.

Comment: When I add new post to the page the post.text in the json file it is not null ( to all the new posts) , the written  value is there. "So what you need to do now is to first check if its not empty only after then you will do your filter" - I don't know how to do this

Comment: Check my updated answer for that. I simply added an AND condition `post.text &&` in post.filter

Comment: I have tried your modified code , the lowerCase error is gone, but when  I type nothing is happening with the posts. Only this is shown Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format

Comment: That error is related with the `time` key

Comment: And without the proper data I'm afraid nobody would be able to help you. I suggest you create a project on stackbliz with your current code so that we can look into it.

Comment: Here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nwk5fb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code since I cannot see the service file.

Here is a simplified working demo for you.  Filters on 'Enter' command to avoid unwanted form submits.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-whqze9?file=src/app/post-list/post.service.ts)

Let me know if it is what you want, and I will explain best as I can.

Currently, you should not be getting any data from the service from your .ts file - at least based on the code you are providing without the Dependency Injection.

Comment: I have tried your code and it still doesn't work . It is still the same error when I type in the search box ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: Filtering works on the Stackblitz with sample values in post.service. Most likely undefined error has something to do with data access from your built service. Can you add sample data of your own post.service - posts array to see if it works?

Comment: Here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nwk5fb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I have built a working demo with db.json.  Filtering works with data, made a couple of changes. You can take a look at this:                             
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/filtering-example-2?file=src/post-list/post-list.component.ts

Comment: With your code the filtering is working. But now there are two problems. This first one is that when I filter I want only the filter posts to appear not all of them ,also the full list of post to disappear. Second problem is that when i try to add a post it doesn't work.   It only works it I remove the filterData funcition( but then the the filtering doesn't work)

Comment: First problem is fixed - just wasn't clearing DOM after filtering. Input wasn't changing filters on Backspace - added that. Second problem - there was an error earlier onSubmit function - added a seperate  addFakePost(). You can check the implementation to see how it works. Adding posts updates the DOM now.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/filtering-example-2?file=src/post-list/post-list.component.ts